# OnCancelListener is not called in DialogFragment

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog, android-dialogfragment

I have a simple `AlertDialog` that displays a list of some items and upon clicking one of them, the clicked item is passed back to the enclosing `Activity`. I also want to perform some default handling when the user cancels the dialog (using the *back button*) - more specifically, I want to pass an empty string to the activity in such case.

However, if I put the dialog in a `DialogFragment` (from the **compatibility package**), the `OnCancelListener` **is not called when I close the dialog with the back button**. What am I doing wrong?

```
public class SelectItemDialog extends DialogFragment {

    public interface Callback {
        void onItemSelected(String string);
    }

    private static final String ARG_ITEMS = "items";

    private Callback callback;

    public static SelectItemDialog fromItems(Collection<String> items) {
        SelectItemDialog fragment = new SelectItemDialog();
        fragment.setArguments(newArguments(items));
        return fragment;
    }

    private static Bundle newArguments(Collection<String> items) {
        Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
        arguments.putStringArray(ARG_ITEMS, items.toArray(new String[items.size()]));
        return arguments;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        callback = (Callback) activity;
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final String[] items = getArguments().getStringArray(ARG_ITEMS);
        return new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
            .setTitle(R.string.dialog_select_email_title)
            .setItems(items, new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    callback.onItemSelected(items[which]);
                }
            })
            .setOnCancelListener(new OnCancelListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
                    // this code is not executed
                    callback.onItemSelected("");
                    throw new RuntimeException("dialog cancelled");
                }
            })
            .create();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 54, accepted):

It might have to do with the fact that there is no explicit call to `cancel()` from your code.
The [OnCancelListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/DialogInterface.OnCancelListener.html) documentation says:

> This will only be called when the dialog is canceled

Which probably needs an explicit `cancel()` call.

Either make a positive/negative button with a `OnClickListener` that calls [`DialogInterface#cancel()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/DialogInterface.html#cancel%28%29) or use a [`OnDismissListener()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/DialogInterface.OnDismissListener.html) with an extra check to see if a list item was clicked.

Also, to listen for a back keypress and cancel the dialog, you can set up an [`OnKeyListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/DialogInterface.OnKeyListener.html), like outlined in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7801971/android-how-to-override-onbackpressed-in-alertdialog/7815342#7815342)

Also, once you have the Dialog set up, it would also be a good idea to use [`Dialog#setCanceledOnTouchOutside()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#setCanceledOnTouchOutside%28boolean%29) in case the the user taps outside the Dialog.

**Edit: The below part is the easy way to handle cancel events in a DialogFragment.**

Since you are using a `DialogFragment`, this class has a very handy method, [`DialogFragment#onCancel()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html#onCancel%28android.content.DialogInterface%29) which gets called when the `DialogFragment` is cancelled. Do your logic in there.

DialogFragments are more complex, with a slightly different lifecycle than normal dialogs. Therefore, first check the documentation if you have a certain `Dialog`-based approach that you are trying to port to a `DialogFragment`, some methods may exist that allow your new implementation to function properly!

Comment: I edited my question. I want the code in the `OnCancelListener` to be called when the dialog is closed with the *back button*.

Comment: @Natix see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7815342/1815485), it's doing the same thing. You have to add an `OnKeyListener` to watch for the back key press.

Comment: Well, this solution should probably work, but if I create the dialog directly inside an activity without a `DialogFragment`, then the `OnCancelListener` is called - both when the back button is pressed or if the user clicks outside the dialog. I don't understand why the `DialogFragment` changes the behaviour.

Comment: @Natix you can try using [the DialogFragment's `onCancel()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html#onCancel(android.content.DialogInterface)). DialogFragments are more complex than regular dialogs.

Comment: `DialogFragment#onCancel()` is exactly what I was looking for! It seems that the `DialogFragment`'s methods override the listeners of the contained `AlertDialog`. Similar case is also the `setCancelable()` method. If you integrate this into your answer, I will accept it.

Comment: @Natix updated my answer, good thing I checked the documentation!

Answer (score 12):

If you are using **DialogFragment** and want to listen back button then use this -

```
    this.getDialog().setOnKeyListener(new Dialog.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(DialogInterface dialog, int keyCode,
                KeyEvent event) {
            if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
                if (****) {
                    your logic
                }
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for actually answering the question! it was the getDialog part which was throwing me off!

Answer (score 11):

**Note: DialogFragment own the Dialog.setOnCancelListener and Dialog.setOnDismissListener callbacks. You must not set them yourself.**

**To find out about these events, override onCancel(DialogInterface) and onDismiss(DialogInterface).**

```
public class SelectItemDialog extends DialogFragment {

    @Override
    public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
        super.onDismiss(dialog);
        //your code hear
        dialog.cancel();
    }
}
```

And you should remove .setOnCancelListener()

Comment: Nice, this should be the correct answer. That little trick is not very clear in this interface.

Answer (score 1):

Actually if you want to use `DialogFragment`, you can never add `OnCancelListener` or `OnDismissListener` to it, since the Dialog Fragment owns callbacks to these methods!

You have 3 options here:

1- go with regular dialogs.
2- set your dialog fragment to cancellable(false) and add a cancel button to the dialog.
3- check @Nikhil Pingle answer.

this is from the documentation of the Dialog Fragment

```
 * <p><em>Note: DialogFragment own the {@link Dialog#setOnCancelListener
 * Dialog.setOnCancelListener} and {@link Dialog#setOnDismissListener
 * Dialog.setOnDismissListener} callbacks.  You must not set them yourself.</em>
 * To find out about these events, override {@link #onCancel(DialogInterface)}
 * and {@link #onDismiss(DialogInterface)}.</p>
```

Answer (score -1):

Cancel Listener or Dismiss listener in DialogFragment can achieve by onDismiss

```
            DialogFragment  newFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
            newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
            newFragment.onDismiss(new DialogInterface(){

                @Override
                public void cancel() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void dismiss() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

            });
```

Comment: This code will actually cause the dialog to be shown and immediately dismissed because of `DialogFragment.onDismiss(...)` call. User won't even see it.